# Integral of a complex function over semicircle enclosing a pole

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function with a pole $x_0$ on the real axis. Why would the integral of that function over the countour that a semicircle that is the upper half of the circle enclosing $x_0$. I cannot figure out why $$\int_C\frac{f(z)}{z-x_0}dz=-\pi i a_{-1}$$
for any analytic $f(z)$, and where we integrate clockwise over $C$. Also, $a_{-1}$ is the residue of $x_0$. This is straightforward to show for the case $f(z)=1$, but how do I generalize?

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Apply cauchy's integral formula using the socalled keyhole-contour.

Comment: I cannot see how I can; the contour is not closed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still can't see how. If I put the pole in the "keyhole" then the pole is not within the contour, and the integral is zero.